# QuantLib Python currency conversion

Tags: quantlib, currency

A simple code below to do currency conversion copied from QuantLib-Python Documentation. This is failing in the EUR to GBP conversion (in the last line of code). Thank you for looking into this.
The ERROR message is-

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udca3' in position 0: surrogates not allowed

```
import QuantLib as ql
usd = ql.USDCurrency()
eur = ql.EURCurrency()
gbp = ql.GBPCurrency()

usdToeur = ql.ExchangeRate(eur, usd, 1.18)
gbpToeur = ql.ExchangeRate(eur, gbp, 0.85)

m_usd = 5 * usd
m_eur = 4.39 * eur
print( 'Converting from USD: ', m_usd, ' = ', usdToeur.exchange(m_usd))
print( 'Converting from EUR: ', m_eur, ' = ', usdToeur.exchange(m_eur))

print(usdToeur.source())
print(usdToeur.target())
print(usdToeur.rate())


print(gbpToeur.source())
print(gbpToeur.target())
print(gbpToeur.rate())

optNotional = 1000000 *eur

print(optNotional)

print(usdToeur.exchange(optNotional))

print(gbpToeur.exchange(optNotional))
```

Comment: What line gives the error?

Comment: The last line of the code

Answer (score 1):

Your last line is trying to print the sterling symbol but it seems it's not compatible with your terminal or your Python interpreter.

You can use

```
print(gbpToeur.exchange(optNotional).value())
```

instead, which doesn't try the fancy formatting and just outputs the number.